# LoadingManager wrong total amount of items to be loaded

Tags: three.js

I am having some problems with the LoadingManager, which I am trying to use to preload my models and textures.

```js
manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
  console.log("loaded: " + loaded + " total: " + total);
};

init();

function init()
{
  // instantiate a loader
  var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
  var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager);
  
  // load first model
  loader.load('model1.obj', function (object) 
  {
    var texture = textureLoader.load('texture1.png');
  });
  
  // load second model
  loader.load('model2.obj', function (object) 
  {
    var texture = textureLoader.load('texture2.png');
  });
}
```

with a console output of:

```
OBJLoader: 80.058837890625ms
loaded: 1 total: 3
loaded: 2 total: 3
OBJLoader.js:787 OBJLoader: 5.671875ms
loaded: 3 total: 4
loaded: 4 total: 4
```

After the first model and texture is loaded, why does the manager think there are 3 total items to be loaded, when there are only two (model1.obj and texture1.png)? Furthermore, the total number of items to be loaded changes from 3 to 4. Is it possible to correct this so that the correct total amount of 4 is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After the first model and texture is loaded, why does the manager think there are 3 total items to be loaded, when there are only two (model1.obj and texture1.png)?

Because the app will start loading both `OBJ` files first and then the textures. So the order is not `model1.obj` => `texture1.png` => `model2.obj` => `texture2.png`. The loading manager will be notified about `model1.obj` and `model2.obj` at the end of `init()`. I suggest you set breakpoints in `LoadingManager.itemStart()` and `LoadingManager.itemEnd()` to better understand the internal loading workflow.

`three.js R104`